# .htaccess conflict

Tags: .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file for Symfony PHP framework project:

```
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domena.pl
  RewriteRule (.*) www.domena.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^index\.php ./ [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The one before last line not working at all. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after requests for domain.com/index.php to be rewritten to domain.com/ then try it without the fullstop

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php / [R=301,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

> Syntax:   RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
>
> The Substitution of a rewrite rule is the string that replaces the
>   original URL-path that was matched by Pattern. The Substitution may be
>   a:
>
> - file-system path
> - URL-path
> - Absolute URL
> - (dash)

Comment: There is no difference :(